# Flutter Cant Connect to firebase firestore database

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

> ```
> Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Parameter format not correct -
> ✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
> Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
> Waiting for Android SDK built for x86 to report its views...
> Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50523/i2wsZclk56g=/ws
> Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
> D/EGL_emulation(18666): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7f04400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdfef9730)
> D/eglCodecCommon(18666): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
> W/DynamiteModule(18666): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
> I/DynamiteModule(18666): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
> W/ProviderInstaller(18666): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote
> ```
>
> version is 0.
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->copyMemory(JJJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getByte(J)B (greylist,core-platform-api, linking,
> allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getByte(Ljava/lang/Object;J)B
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking,
> allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putByte(JB)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking,
> allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putByte(Ljava/lang/Object;JB)V
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J
> (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> I/xample.news_ap(18666): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
> I/chatty  (18666): uid=10143(com.example.news_app) AsyncTask #1 identical 1 line
> I/xample.news_ap(18666): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
> V/NativeCrypto(18666): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native
> methods...
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String;
> (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> D/NetworkSecurityConfig(18666): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
> I/ProviderInstaller(18666): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
>
> ```
> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#f839b):
> The getter 'length' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: length
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:
>   Home file:///E:/major%20project/newssapp/news_app/lib/main.dart:17:15
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
> #1      _HomeState.build (package:news_app/home.dart:151:44)
> #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4663:28)
> #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4546:15)
> #4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
> #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
> #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
> #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4710:11)
> #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
> ...     Normal element mounting (132 frames)
> #140    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
> #141    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5991:32)
> ...     Normal element mounting (267 frames)
> #408    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
> #409    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
> #410    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1174:16)
> #411    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1145:5)
> #412    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1087:17)
> #413    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2620:19)
> #414    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1086:13)
> #415    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:927:7)
> #416    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:908:7)
> (elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
>
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection,
> ```
>
> allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, JNI, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
> (greylist, reflection, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;
> (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
> W/xample.news_ap(18666): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking,
> allowed)
> W/Firestore(18666): (21.4.3) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error:
> Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=The project newsapp-aa434 does not
> exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud
> Firestore database. Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to
> create a project or
> https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=newsapp-aa434
> to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud
> Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app
> and this app must not be disabled., cause=null}
> W/Firestore(18666): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will
> operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to
> the backend.
>
> ```
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#f839b):
> The getter 'length' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: length
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was: 
>   Home file:///E:/major%20project/newssapp/news_app/lib/main.dart:17:15
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
> #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
> #1      _HomeState.build (package:news_app/home.dart:151:44)
> #2      StatefulElement.bu``ild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4663:28)
> #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4546:15)
> #4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
> ...
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> ```

Comment: You seem to have just posted your error. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Using a code block around your error would have made it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest Firebase dependencies then you have to add the [Firebase Core](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#installation) to your dependencies in pubspec.yaml;

```
firebase_core: "0.5.0"
```

After integrating the Core dependency you have to initialize Firebase in your app to access it's features such Firestore;

```
void main() {
     runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize Firebase:
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return YourApplication();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The necessary documents for the installation and usage of Firebase tools in Flutter can be found in [FlutterFire page](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview).

Alternatively, If you are sure about your dependencies, you can run in your terminal the following command;

```
flutter pub get
```